# Trying to figure out Core Audio's NBandEQ

Tags: ios, c, audio, core-audio, audiounit

So I am trying to figure out the ill documented NBandEQ that Apple added in iOS 5. I am able to get it to work great for anything under 16 bands but I want more :) What happens is that if I make it a 15 band EQ everything works but if I go any number 16 and up I get a -10851 (`kAudioUnitErr_InvalidPropertyValue`) error when I am setting `kAUNBandEQProperty_NumberOfBands` then the first 8 bands set up fine and the rest result in the -10878 (`kAudioUnitErr_InvalidParameter`) error. So 15 bands can successfully be done but when I go to 16 all of a sudden only 8 can be done. There is `kAUNBandEQProperty_MaxNumberOfBands` that I can read that I assumed would be the limit that the device in its current state could handle. Well it spits out erratic numbers everything from 12 digit numbers to 4 digit numbers. I think to myself does it not like the extreme frequencies I am giving it. I eliminated that possibility. Then I realized that the bandwidth of the bands may be overlapping and it doesn't like that. so I reduce the bandwidth from the default .5 to the min. .05 no help there ether.

I did realize that after all my messing around with the settings that was all silly because it starts complaining before I even get to those settings. It is already giving and error in the number of bands.

I am posting this question to see if any more experienced programers can see something in my code that is messing me up and point it out to me. I realize that not to many have venture into core audio much less NBandEQ but maybe I am messing up some basic C so please have a look. I will be very thankful. I am frustrated obviously. Also in posting this code (even tho it is ugly test code) maybe I can help others that come behind. I know I wish there was at least one snippet of code out there that I could have had a look at in relation to NBandEQ

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
    //Getting max bands for this device???
UInt32 maxNumOfBands;
UInt32 propSize = sizeof(maxNumOfBands);
AudioUnitGetProperty([_equilizer audioUnit],
                     kAUNBandEQProperty_MaxNumberOfBands,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                     0,
                     &maxNumOfBands,
                     &propSize);
NSLog(@"THIS IS THE MAX NUMBER OF BANDS?---%u",(unsigned int)maxNumOfBands);

UInt32 noBands = [eqFrequencies count];
// Set the number of bands first
NSLog(@"NumberOfBands atempted:%i with result:%ld", (unsigned int)noBands, AudioUnitSetProperty(_equilizer.audioUnit,
                     kAUNBandEQProperty_NumberOfBands,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                     0,
                     &noBands,
                     sizeof(noBands)));
// Set the frequencies
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<noBands; i++) {
   NSLog(@"Set Frequency for band:%i with result:%ld", i, AudioUnitSetParameter([_equilizer audioUnit],
                          kAUNBandEQParam_Frequency+i,
                          kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                          0,
                          (AudioUnitParameterValue)[[eqFrequencies objectAtIndex:i] floatValue],
                          0));
}
 //set bandwidth
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<noBands; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Set bandwidth for band:%i with result:%ld", i, AudioUnitSetParameter([_equilizer audioUnit],
                          kAUNBandEQParam_Bandwidth+i,
                          kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                          0,
                          0.05,//of octive
                          0));
}

// Set the bypass to off "0"
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<noBands; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Set Bypass for band:%i with result:%ld", i, AudioUnitSetParameter([_equilizer audioUnit],
                                                   kAUNBandEQParam_BypassBand+i,
                                                   kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                                   0,
                                                   0,//off
                                                   0));
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I figured it out. I had used `kAudioUnitScope_Output` on the `kAUNBandEQProperty_MaxNumberOfBands` it should be `kAudioUnitScope_Global`.

`kAUNBandEQProperty_MaxNumberOfBands` resulted in 16 on Sim, iPhone 5, and Retina Ipad.

Comment: This is the answer to the problem but I'm not sure it is cool to mark my own answer cause it seems like that could be abused to be able to rack up reputation. Please let me know how I should do this. If someone else wants to just answer it I could mark them as the answer.

Comment: Also I would love to know if the number is different on different devices. These are the only devices I have access to. Would love it if people posted their results.

Comment: It's fine if you accept your own answer.  You won't get reputation for it.  You solved the problem, accepting it is the right way to indicate that here is the answer.